# How can I create contours of 0.1 or 0.2 instead of 1?

Tags: spatial-analyst

The default value is 1 and I have salinity values from 33 to 35 and therefore only contours 34 and 35 can be created with the contour interval 1... But I want it smaller so I can see contours 34.1, 34.2, .... 34.9, 35.0.....

Comment: What is the data type of your salinity raster? is it integer? that might explain the problem if any.

Answer (score 4):

The Contour tool in Spatial Analyst will work with any positive number, including decimals, entered  into the *Contour interval* field.  If you expand the *Show help* button at the bottom of the tool dialog box, and click in the *Contour interval* field, the help dialog will state: "The interval, or distance, between contour lines. This can be any positive number."

In your specific situation, you can simply enter "0.1" as the contour interval and the output will consist of contour lines in one-tenth increments as you describe.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, this place is a great resource. I've made a couple of anonymous contributions in the past, figured I go legitimate and start reaping the rewards!

Comment: I see you have *four* accounts!  Why don't you merge them and collect all your reputation in one place?  Go to http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge and just fill out the form.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was causing the Issue.  I had already tried entering "0.1" and it did not want to work. I later found out that "0,1" worked because I am working on a laptop with European locale. Most European Locale use comma instead of dot for a [decimal separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @iant How does this not answer the question? It seems to me that it resolves it--especially as the answer comes from the OP!

Comment: @whuber - it's more of a comment than an answer